# Why model records are not displayed?

Tags: python, django

I ran into a system problem yesterday, the problem is that the model records are not displayed on the page, even though they were displayed before, I don’t know what the problem is, since everything worked before

this is code views.py

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
template_name = 'Homepage/index.html'
model = Goods
context_object_name = 'goods'
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    numbers = Number.objects.all()
    context['numbers'] = numbers
    return context
```

this is code of html

```html
{% for number in numbers %}
              <h3 class="numbers">{{numbers.number1_text}}</h3>
           {% endfor %}

           {% for number in numbers %}
              <h3 class="numbers">{{numbers.number2_text}}</h3>
           {% endfor %}
```

this is code of models.py

```
class Number(models.Model):
number1_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
number2_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)

def __str__(self):
    return self.number1_text

def __str__(self):
    return self.number2_text
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo here

```
           {% for number in numbers %}
              <h3 class="numbers">{{numbers.number1_text}}</h3>
                                          ^here it should be number
           {% endfor %}

           {% for number in numbers %}
              <h3 class="numbers">{{numbers.number2_text}}</h3>
           {% endfor %}
```

Correct code

```
           {% for number in numbers %}
              <h3 class="numbers">{{number.number1_text}}</h3>
           {% endfor %}

           {% for number in numbers %}
              <h3 class="numbers">{{number.number2_text}}</h3>
           {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Still doesn't work

Comment: @Licrencie Are you sure there are Numbers in the database?

Comment: Not really, but the model is registered in the admin panel and shows her entries there

Comment: Also, when I run `py manage.py sqlmigrate App 0001`, it shows me that such a table is being created